# C emulating terminal

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write this code that emulats an user-input terminal.
User input should consists of 3 commands and print them if all of them present otherwise print the error message.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    char command[1000], variable[1000], value[1000];
    while(1)
    {
        printf("root@superstars:~# ");
        scanf("%s" , command);
        if (strcmp(command, "") != 0){
           scanf(" %s" , variable);
           if (strcmp(variable, "") != 0){
              scanf("  %s" , value);
              if (strcmp(value, "") != 0){
                 printf("%s %s %s\n", command, variable, value);
              } else { printf("Command incorrect\n"); }
           } else { printf("Command incorrect\n"); }
        } else { printf("Command incorrect\n"); }

    }
}
```

But the problem is that it is working only if the command is correct consisting of 3 words. If fail nothing happen, i just get a blank line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) function to achieve this. So it would be something like this:

```
char input[3000];
int arg;

fgets(input, 3000, stdin);
arg = sscanf(input, "%s %s %s", command, variable, value);
if(arg != 3)
    printf("Command incorrect\n");
else
    printf("%s %s %s\n", command, variable, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` returns `EOF` on end of input

Hence, use a loop to read until end of stream

```
char args[100][20];
int  i =0;
while(scanf("%s",args[i++])!=EOF);
if(i!=3)
{
    //fail
}
```

Using this approach, you can handle commands with any number of arguments.